# brew upgrade git fetch error, yet repo can download with git clone?

Tags: git, emacs, homebrew

On `brew --version => 0.9.5` the following error happens. Even if I  `brew uninstall emacs` and install instead of upgrade, same error.

I can `git clone` that same url in the brew printout and it can connect and clone the repo no problem. Did i muck up the repo that brew uses, somehow, locally? `brew doctor` has nothing and i'm up to date on brew as of this morning.

Thoughts?

```
brew upgrade --cocoa --HEAD emacs
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
emacs HEAD
==> Upgrading emacs
==> Cloning http://git.sv.gnu.org/r/emacs.git
Updating /Library/Caches/Homebrew/emacs--git
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Error: Failed to download resource "emacs"
Failure while executing: git fetch -q origin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing out your cache:

```
rm -r /Library/Caches/Homebrew/emacs--git
```

Or fetching with --force:

```
brew fetch emacs --HEAD --force
```

Comment: `brew fetch` in your answer, was the answer. didn't try the `rm` route. Thanks!